# How to reconstruct a URL from a JavaScript function?

Tags: javascript, url, window.location

I am trying to reconstruct a [URL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Locator) that links to a [CSV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) file. Right now, the link calls a JavaScript function called `downloadCsv()`. The link looks like this:

```
<a href="javascript:downloadCsv()">
```

The function looks like this:

```
function downloadCsv() {
    window.location = urlMap.createReportingUrl('entitiesSummaryJson', {
        csv: true,
        "metrics": metricsForTables
    }, 'entityId');
}
```

The `urlMap` variable above looks like this:

```
var urlMap = {
    params: {
        appSpotOrAppCircleData: '2',
        intervalCut: '30Days',
        entityId: '0',
        entityType: 'advertiserOverview',
        zoom: 'd'
    },

    toUrl : function(params) {
        var paramValues = [];
        $.each(params, function(key, value) {
           paramValues.push(key + '=' + value);
        });
        return '.do?' + paramValues.join('&');
    },

    createReportingUrl : function(baseUrl, fieldToAdd, fieldToRemove) {
        var params = $.extend({}, urlMap.params, fieldToAdd);
        delete params[fieldToRemove];
        return adjustAppSpotUrl(baseUrl + urlMap.toUrl(params));
    }
};
```

And the `baseUrl` looks like this:

```
https://dev.flurry.com/advertisersReportingEntities.do?zoom=d&intervalCut=30Days&entityType=advertiserOverview&appSporOrAppCircleData=2
```

I don't know JavaScript so I'm stuck here - is there a way to reconstruct the URL from the information above? I'm trying to define a set of logic that can take information from the [HTML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML) and automatically download the CSV by pointing to the download URL and writing the file.

How can I fix this problems?

Answer (score -1):

I think you should use something like

```
window.open(strUrl)
```

after you reconstruct your URL.

So it should looks like:

```
<a href="Your ULR if JS is disabled" target="_blank" onclick="downloadCsv();return false">my link</a>

function downloadCsv() {
    var params = "menubar=yes,location=yes,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,status=yes";
    var url = urlMap.createReportingUrl('entitiesSummaryJson', {
        csv: true,
        "metrics": metricsForTables
    }, 'entityId');
    window.open(url, "My JSON", params);//open URL in new tab in browser
}
```

Try it. It should work.

So, don't use the protocol "javascript:". It's obsolete and if on the client JavaScript is disabled, it will not work.

In case you want not only an open file, but place it on the HDD, actually it's impossible without interaction with the user. It may be malware or so, browser does not allow to do it without the dialog box. To show a dialog box on the client, try using a special header:

```
'Content-Type: application/force-download'.
```

Comment: To clarify - I am not asking how I should change the code in the original post - I am merely a user of their website, accessing the page with the JavaScript. I want to review the JavaScript of the website, and determine what url the `downloadCsv()' function calls so that I can automate the download of the csv file.